# How to do ssh to machine which is connected via other machine using python (parmaiko)

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

1. Note currently I'm using paramiko library to connect to machine
   now the requirement is am suppose to connect to machine B once i connect machine A

flow :-- ssh to machine A and then ssh to machine B from machine A and do some activity on machine B

Could any body let me know how can i do that ?

thanks in advance :),

Comment: @MartinPrikryl , Thanks for the response, Kindly note i have added your code but observing below error

Secsh channel 0 open FAILED: open failed: Administratively prohibited
paramiko.ssh_exception.ChannelException: ChannelException(1, 'Administratively prohibited')

i have gone through other docs it says 
@/etc/ssh/ssh_config file 
AllowTcpForwarding need to be set to "no" or needs to be commented out 

but my case its already commented out 

any idea on what might be causing this issue?
thanks :)

Comment: It needs to be set to `yes`.

Comment: still the error is the same martin

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well allowing port forwarding on the server is not a programming question. Please ask that on [su].